# Load a large .csv file from a .tar.gz file into Hive Table

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

I have a large `.csv` file stored in a `.tar.gz` file and would like to put it's contents into a Hive table. Unfortunately, there isn't enough disk space for me to unzip the `.csv` file.

I have tried the following (and variations of the following):

```
Set Hive.exec.compress.output = true;
Set io.seqfile.compression.type = block;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db.test;
CREATE TABLE db.test
 (var1 STRING, . . . varn STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n';

create table test_seq 
stored as sequencefile as
 select * from test ;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/db/test.tar.gz' INTO TABLE db.test;

create table test_seq
stored as sequencefile as
 select * from test;

SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 10;
```

But the resulting table only contains NULL values. Any suggestions why?

Answer (score -2):

you should replace second 'fields terminated ' by 'lines terminated '.